# Getting schema_name from schema_id on a remote SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, information-schema

I have to run various queries over multiple databases and collect the results *as a result set*, so an `sp_MSforeach` approach won't work. I'm actually collecting data about the databases, schemas, and objects within those servers to provide some utility functions.

The information schemas work well when they work but for some things you need the `sys` views, such as `sys.synonyms`. This, over a linked server:

```
select *
from <remote_server>.<database>.sys.synonyms
```

This gets me, for example, `schema_id`. I need to get the schema name from the `schema_id`. I can't use `SCHEMA_NAME()` because that works in the context of this database on this server, not in the context of the remote, linked database on the remote server. What I would need is something like this (invented syntax):

```
select 
    *, 
    <remote_server>.<database>.SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)
from
    <remote_server>.<database>.sys.synonyms
```

which AFAIK, does not exist.

I could use the `information_schema.schemata` views except

1. they don't mix well with MS's catalogue views (which too often just report internal ID numbers for things) plus
2. BOL continually warns you not to trust the schema info from `information_schema` results.

So a few questions, firstly how do I get the schema name from the `schema_id` when that `schema_id` has been taken from a remote server?

Second, does anyone know of any comprehensive documentation or even better, a good book, that covers these catalogue views that supplant the old `information_schema` views, because using them is a royal pain.

Comment: What's wrong with `sys.schemas`? Personally I rarely use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` and stick to the `sys` objects as I know that anything I need *will* be in there.

Comment: Also `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` isn't "old", it's an ANSI-SQL "thing".

Comment: @ThomA - did you close the question? Edit: who closed this without reading it?

Comment: I'm not sure why who closed the question is relevant; are you saying the linked question doesn't answer the question? If so, you should [edit] to explain why.

Comment: If you got an actual reason to reopen then happy to reopen this. But as far as I can see, the linked answer should suffice: you should use `sys.schemas` rather than `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` so you can just do `select * from remoteserver.db.sys.schemas where schema_id = @schemaid`. Your second question is off-topic for [so], for recommendations it's much better to post on [softwarerecs.se]

Comment: So what is "wrong" about the closure, user3779002 ? What about the linked duplicate doesn't answer the question? As @Charlieface mentions, the second part of your question, asking for "a good book" is off-topic here on  [so], which only leaves the first part; how to get the schema name from it's id. The linked duplicate demonstrate how to do that with `sys.schemas`, which I referenced in my first comment. Why are you unable to implement that solution? What about your attempts to implement it didn't work? What were those attempts?

Comment: @Charlieface  The partly right answer is yours: 'select * from remoteserver.db.sys.schemas where...', but it's wrng in that it's coming from several DBs ("multiple databases" I said) and a schema_id is unique only within one. OK, I can work around that I think.
Saying the other 2 answers are relevant is wrong. The first is someone who didn't know of sys.schemas, the 2nd proposes info_schema to get the schema which as the respondent there said, and likewise I said, is *cautioned against* by MS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK it seems you want to query system views for multiple databases and/or servers in one resultset. This is always difficult, as it requires a big `UNION ALL` query including each database, and if you only have them in variables then you need dynamic SQL.

Let us assume you have the databases in a table variable

```sql
DECLARE @dbs TABLE (server sysname, dbname sysname);
```

Then generate a big `UNION ALL` of all of them and execute it.

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SELECT @sql = STRING_AGG(CAST('
SELECT
  schema_id,
  name,
  db = ' + QUOTENAME(dbs.dbname, '''') + '
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(dbs.server) + '.' + QUOTENAME(dbs.dbname) + '.sys.schemas
' AS nvarchar(max)), '
UNION ALL')
FROM @dbs dbs;

PRINT @sql;  -- your friend

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

If you have any parameters, including table valued parameters, you can pass them through via `sp_executesql`. Do *not* inject them as text.

For example, to find `@schema_id` in all databases:

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SELECT @sql = STRING_AGG(CAST('
SELECT
  id,
  name,
  db = ' + QUOTENAME(dbs.dbname, '''') + '
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(dbs.server) + '.' + QUOTENAME(dbs.dbname) + '.sys.schemas
WHERE schema_id = @schema_id
' AS nvarchar(max)), '
UNION ALL')
FROM @dbs dbs;

PRINT @sql;  -- your friend

EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
  N'@schema_id int',
  @schema_id = @schema_id;
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Thank you, this is spot-on (you may need to change 'id' to' schema_id', and I'll need to include the server name in the result set, but otherwise this is perfect). NB. thanks for the "don't inject text" tip for sp_executesql, I'll do some reading on it.

Comment: Long and short is: anything which is a value can be passed as a parameter, but if it is part of the syntax of what you are querying (such as object names, or `ASC` `DESC`) then you need to inject it.